# Kotlin: Lambdas, range, map, filter and reduce/fold

Tags: lambda, kotlin, range

Using the functions such as lambdas, range, map, filter and reduce/fold, calculate the sum of numbers between 1 and 1000 which are divisible by 5 or 3 and print the result.

Comment: Could you show what have you tried so far, and what have you stumble at?

Answer (score 0):

We can do the following:

```
println((1..1000).filter{ it % 3 == 0 || it % 5 == 0 }.reduce{sum, element -> sum + element})
```

Instead of reduce we could use `sum` as well which would look like this:

```
println((1..1000).filter{ it % 3 == 0 || it % 5 == 0 }.sum())
```