# Kotlin - using Lambda functions range, map, filter, reduce/fold to find the sum of all numbers between 1-1000 that are divisible by 3 or 5

Tags: function, lambda, kotlin

I am trying to use Lambda functions to find the sum of numbers between 1-1000 that are divisible by 3 or 5. I have to complete the task in Kotlin.

So far all I have is:

```
fun divisibleByThreeOrFive () { 
}
```

So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132231/kotlin-lambdas-range-map-filter-and-reduce-fold ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talking about "numbers from *x* to *y*" makes me think of the [`IntRange`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/index.html) class. You can use the [`rangeTo()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/range-to.html) function to generate your `IntRange` in a nicely-readable fashion, or you can use the `(x..y)` syntax to do it if you prefer.

Talking about only those that are "divisible by 3 or 5" makes me think of the [`filter()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) function that accepts a predicate.

Talking about the sum of these numbers makes me think of the [`sum()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum.html) function.

Put it all together and you get:

```
val sum = 1.rangeTo(1000)
    .filter { it % 3 == 0 || it % 5 == 0 }
    .sum()
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you